# HTTP post with image and data

Tags: java, http-headers, http-post, apache-commons-httpclient

I am using apache HTTP Client for callin rest endpoints.

I want to call a POST request with image and some more form data as parameters. I can do them separately with to requests like first for the form data and the other for the image alone.

Is there any possible solution so that i can do it with one request.

Below is the api call

```
http://<url>?hint=hi&def=ready&image=<imagefile>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Multipart Request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Multipart_messages). [Commons Apache File Upload API](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/) has very good API for the same. 
Apache Commons HttpClient has the API for client also.

Else, use Servlet 3.0 container which has support for multipart data. Where the **String part** type will be provided with [HttpServletRequest.getParameter()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29) method. And the **File type** parts can be retrieved using [HttpServletRequest.getPart()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) method.

Comment: Thanks Ramesh.. I am actually using what you pointed. But I dont know how to make a request with both UrlEncodedFormEntity and MultipartEntity as defined in the Commons Apache. Bascially, i need a single POST request with both MultipartEntity for image and UrlEncodedFormEntity for the form details.

Comment: I am saying dont use both, send those url paramters like multipart form date. Which can have images and sting which are nothing but Parameters.

Comment: Updated my answer. can please check.

Comment: Thanks Ramesh. But I used FileItemFactory and completed :-)